# Windows 10 puts boot files on wrong drive

Tags: windows-10, boot

I have a machine with an m.2 (NVME) drive for booting, and a couple of larger SATA drives. Since the m.2 port has a higher drive number in UEFI/BIOs, Windows always tries to install it's boot files to the SATA drives, even if the O/S installs to the m.2.  I get around that by disabling the SATA drives at install time.

The real problem though, when Windows 10 Update takes a major update, it has a bad habit of relocating the boot files from the m.2 drive to the SATA drive (I'm guessing it's because the SATA has a lower drive number when it enumerates the drives).  As a result, my PC becomes unbootable, and I have to then configure the D: drive as the boot drive in the firmware setup.  Is there any way to fix this so that Windows installs its boot files to the correct drive?  I'm willing to reinstall Windows for a permanent fix.

Answer (score 1):

I have two 2TB drives in my Windows 10 Desktop computer and it unerringly boots to the correct drive.

I do not know if you can re-establish the drives for a truly permanent solution.

Since you are willing to re-install Windows 10, then you can get a permanent fix.

Back up all you need on a USB Drive.

Turn off, remove the "second" drive.

Start up, use the full Windows 10 install so that it assigns the "first" drive as Device 0 and makes the 3 (minimum) partitions.

Make sure it is all correct and boots correctly and unerringly.

Then turn off, install the other drive and make sure it comes up as Drive 1.  If it is a boot drive, back it up and format it so it is not (that get rid of remnants of its ownership of the system).

When you are done, it will work just fine. I have it working here just fine.

Comment: Thank John -- I have done that very thing in the past, but it only fixes it temporarily.  When Microsoft releases a major update to windows, like the 2004 build, the updater ends up moving the boot sector back to the D: drive.  I've used multiple drives for upwards of 20 years, but for SATA, I always put my boot drive on SATA connector 0.  Since I want my boot drive to be the NVme, it seems to enumerate it last.  (note -- this is not the same thing as the boot order you set in bios, I'm talking about the order that you see in a tool like diskpart

Comment: The way I have suggested above (install Windows first and with only one drive in place) will be permanent. It will always work and has done for me over the years.  Adding a second (non-bootable drive) to a working system has never changed my drive assignment or boot order.